# cv2.findContours issues, opencv

Tags: python, opencv

I am trying to run some code from Kaggle, but I am unable to.

The code is [here](https://www.kaggle.com/chattob/intel-mobileodt-cervical-cancer-screening/cervix-segmentation-gmm).

The error message is:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
IndexError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-6-2a3e36c2605f> in <module>()
     59         _, contours_mask, _ = cv2.findContours(thresh_mask.copy(),cv2.RETR_TREE,cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_NONE)
     60 
---> 61         main_contour = sorted(contours_mask, key = cv2.contourArea, reverse = True)[0]
     62 
     63         x,y,w,h = cv2.boundingRect(main_contour)

IndexError: list index out of range
```

It might be Python or package version related, as other people haven't experienced the code.

I tried opening some outputs but I am new to cv2.

To my understanding:

```
cv2.findContours() -> image, contours, hierarchy
```

What I do get:

```
cv2.findContours(thresh_mask.copy(),cv2.RETR_TREE,cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_NONE) -> (array([[0, 0, 0, ..., 0, 0, 0],
    [0, 0, 0, ..., 0, 0, 0],
    [0, 0, 0, ..., 0, 0, 0],
    ..., 
    [0, 0, 0, ..., 0, 0, 0],
    [0, 0, 0, ..., 0, 0, 0],
    [0, 0, 0, ..., 0, 0, 0]], dtype=uint8), [], None)
```

Hence, countours is empty, which might be the problem.
thresh_mask is an all zero matrix for that case, which might be the cause. Unsure of it though.

Any hints/advice?

Comment: Yes you are right `countours is empty, which might be the problem`, You may need to adjust the parameters of the methods which are generating the binary images

Comment: A comment in article reads: *The codes published in the Kernels section can help you to start your project and you can take them like an start point, but they are not the final solution. Good luck!*

Comment: May I see `len(sorted(contours_mask, key = cv2.contourArea, reverse = True))`

Comment: len(sorted(contours_mask, key = cv2.contourArea, reverse = True)) = 0

Comment: @epattaro This means there are no contours present. As menioned you have to check your `thresh_mask` variable

Answer (score 2):

It happens because your input image (thresh_mask) is empty i.e complete black. No contours are detected.
Please check contents of thresh_mask  or display it using cv2.imshow.

Comment: If the `thresh_mask` is completely white, I presume `cv2.findContours()` would find at least **1 contour**.

Comment: Thanks Luke , you are right.I have edited my answer.